Prove that a fuction $T(n)$ is $O(n)$
I'm studying algorithms and i have to prove that
$T(n) = O(n)$ where  $T(n) = \frac{1}{2}n^2 + 3n$
I'd like to submit an observation of mine and ask if it's correct.
If $T(n) = O(n)$ than there exist positive constants $c$ and $n0$ such that $T(n) \leq c \cdot f(n)$ for all $n \geq n0$, so:
$\frac{1}{2}n^2 + 3n \leq c \cdot n$
developing the inequality we have:
$\frac{1}{2}n + 3 \leq c$
We can see that no matter what constant $c$ we take, there will always be an $n$ such that the left member will exceed the right member, since $\frac{1}{2}n + 3$ grows linearly.
So $T(n) \notin O(n)$
Now, another way of seeing this, wouldn't be to notice that, no matter $c$ we take, the solution of the inequality will always be something like $n \leq a$ and therefore the original inequality can't hold for all $n \geq n0$  ?
For example:
for $c = 5$, than the inequality holds for $n \leq 4$
for $c = 13$, than the inequality holds for $n \leq 20$
for $c = 1000$, than the inequality holds for $n \leq 1994$
and so on.

Why the downvoting? Might be that similar questions were asked but i've never seen the observation i made. I just want to learn.

You reasoning is correct.
Just a little remark, the definition you use is for positive quantities, else you have to use absolute values.
Note that $3n=O(n)$ so comparing $T(n)$ and $O(n)$ comes down to comparing $\frac 12n^2$ to $O(n)$.
Since $O(\cdot)$ notations absorb multiplicative constants, the question boils down to is $n^2\stackrel{?}{=}O(n)$ ?
We can divide by $n$ as you noticed so the question is simply is $n\stackrel{?}{=}O(1)$
Which is clearly false as $n$ is unbounded, and $O(1)$ means bounded.
In general the question is $T(n)=O(f(n))$ provided $f(n)\neq 0$ can always be rewritten as $\frac{T(n)}{f(n)}=O(1)$ in other words, is this ratio bounded ?
